# Backup a big file with binary diff

Tags: backup, filesystems

**Edited**

here is my problem:

I have a file A (10GB) and a file B (10GB).

File A and B are slightly different (diff is around 500MB).

I want to the file A to be exactly as B as fast as possible. One obvious solution is

```
$ cp B A
```

Is there any faster solution?

Comment: The type of backup your looking for is a [Differential Backup](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differential_backup) there are tons of software solutions to acomplish your goals.